# How to retain the values in textbox if there occurs some error after validation while saving in jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a jsp page where I have few text fields and after saving if trhe user missed to give some data,the entire textfields data is going.Please help me to retain the datas in jsp page after error also.

in my code there is something like:
 ---is it because of this the datas  are getting hidden?

Comment: Did you try to use JQuery form validation to validate your form in the client side?
Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I dont want to have the validation,I want to retain the data in textfileds even if there some error occurs after saving.Now if error comes the entire data gets lose and need to nter it again.I want to retain the datas.